# Производительность массивов

Tags: массивы, java, производительность

Будет ли быстрее итерация по одномерному массиву, чем по трехмерному?
И так же хотелось бы узнать, на сколько, потому, что в моем проекте удобнее трехмерный, но производительность на первом плане.

Comment: Если производительность на самом деле важна, то пишите на Си.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

По идее итерация по одномурному массиву должна быть быстрее, чем три цикла по трёхмерному. Но наиболее вероятно, вы не заметите разницы, так как большая часть времени будет теряться на другое. Т.е. накладные расходы на итерацию - жалкие гроши. Игнорируйте их.

Так что берите трёхмерный, если он удобнее и используйте его.

Comment: Не знаю, как в Java, но вообще, далеко не всегда гроши. В процессоре, скорее всего, предсказание переходов будет ломаться на каждом выходе из внутреннего цикла. Если бы Java была супер-тормозным языком сам по себе, можно было бы сказать, что это падение производит. не заметно. Но т.к. многие приверженцы Java считают её прямо-таки быстрой, так говорить нельзя.



Вобщем, если производительность важна - поменьше вложенных циклов, циклы с меньшим количеством итераций делайте внешними и измеряйте скорость (может быть плохо из-за непоследовательного доступа к памяти)